# Make a table of string frequency

Tags: r, analysis, frequency

I am trying to make a summary table of many strings. My data looks like this:

```
x<-c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d")
```

How would I analyse the recurrence of each string at once? Ideally to produce a table of frequency like this (I presume it would be easy to sort for decreasing frequency):

```
"a" 2
"b" 1
"c" 3
"d" 1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this to make the frecuency table:

```
table(x)
```

To sort just use sort.

```
sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

Similarly,

```
rle(sort(x))
```

will do the counting; you can then sort the results as desired.